# Bootstrap's Pagination - unable to navigate to previous page ( reactjs )

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

Am implemented Bootstrap's pagination in my reactjs application. Am able to navigate to next page but am not able to navigate to previous pages. While clicking on the previous page its navigate to next page only..

Apart from this previous page issue, rest of the functinality is working fine as per pagination logic.

Could you please help me out on the same.

Please find my code below.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  };
    this.handlePageChange=this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
  }

  getNumPages(currentPage) {
    { this.handlePageChange } 
      this.setState({
        per_page: this.props.results ,
        currentPage: currentPage + 1 ,
        previousPage: currentPage - 1
      });
    }

  handlePageChange(page, evt) {
    const currentPage = this.state.currentPage || 1;
    const numPages = this.getNumPages();
    const pageLinks = [];
    if (currentPage > 1) {
    if (currentPage > 2) {
      pageLinks.push(1);
      pageLinks.push(' ');
    }
      pageLinks.push(currentPage - 1);
      pageLinks.push(' ');
    }
    for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
      const page = i;
      pageLinks.push(page);
    }
    if (currentPage < numPages) {
      pageLinks.push(' ');
      pageLinks.push(currentPage + 1);
      if (currentPage < numPages - 1) {
        pageLinks.push(' ');
        pageLinks.push(numPages);
      }
    }
    this.setState({ currentPage: currentPage + 1  } );
    this.setState({ previousPage: currentPage - 1  } );
  }

  render() {
    const per_page = "10";
    const paginationData = this.props.results;
    let numPages = Math.ceil(paginationData.length / per_page);
    if (paginationData.length % per_page > 0) {
      numPages++;
    }
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-primary">
        <div className="panel-heading">ORDERS LIST</div>
        <table className="table table-hover" }} >
          <thead >
            <tr>
              <th>Customer Name</th>
              <th>Assignee</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Creation Date </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <SearchResultsList items={ this.props.results } open={ this.props.open } 
          current_Page={ this.state.currentPage }  />
        </table>

        <Pagination id="content" className="users-pagination pull-right" 
        bsSize="medium" 
        first last  next  prev  boundaryLinks items={numPages} 
        activePage={ this.state.currentPage } onSelect={ this.handlePageChange } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please look into these: 1) why are you not giving an initial state inside constructor ? Set `this.state = { currentPage: 1 }` 2) What does this line `{ this.handlePageChange }` do inside `getNumPages` ? 3) Why not binding `getNumPages` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the working code.

Have to pass the page number in the handlePageChange(page) and have to set the page number for the current page (this.setState({ currentPage: page } );).

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {  };
}

handlePageChange(page) {
this.setState({ currentPage: page } );
}

render() {
  return (
  <div className="panel panel-primary">
    <div className="panel-heading">ORDERS LIST</div>
    <table className="table table-hover" }} >
      <thead >
        <tr>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Assignee</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Creation Date </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <SearchResultsList items={ this.props.results } open={ this.props.open 
     } 
      current_Page={ this.state.currentPage }  />
    </table>

    <Pagination id="content" className="users-pagination pull-right" 
    bsSize="medium" 
    first last  next  prev  boundaryLinks items={numPages} 
    activePage={ this.state.currentPage } onSelect={ this.handlePageChange } 
    />
   </div>
   );
  }
}
```